# How can i convert box shadow to filter drop shadow?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to convert box-shadow property value to filter drop-shadow?

I have tried doing this:

```css
.boxes-container {
 display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.boxshadow-box,
.filter-dropshadow-box {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxshadow-box {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.filter-dropshadow-box {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) drop-shadow(8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14)) drop-shadow(3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12));
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes-container">
  <div class="boxshadow-box"></div>
  <div class="filter-dropshadow-box"></div>
</div>
```

But I can't reach the same results for drop-shadow as box-shadow.

Comment: No spread-radius to drop-shadow nope... Ps: not even in svg-filters.

Comment: note that drop-shadow are cumulative so each one consider the previous one unline box-shadow or text-shadow that are independant. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016277/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. By Mistake, you passed the wrong value in filter drop-shadow.

```css
.boxes-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.boxshadow-box,
.filter-dropshadow-box {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxshadow-box {
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.filter-dropshadow-box {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) drop-shadow( 0px 8px 10px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14));
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 5px 5px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)) drop-shadow( 0px 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14));
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes-container">
    <div class="boxshadow-box"></div>
    <div class="filter-dropshadow-box"></div>
</div>
```